# Adding song to itunes with C# sdk/api

Tags: c#, itunes

I'm looking for an SDK or API (c#) that would allow me to add songs to my itunes library. If anybody knows of one, that would be a big help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[iTunes COM library](http://developer.apple.com/SDK/). It requires COM interop though. However, there should be some documentation in there.

Comment: knoopx -> you can use AppleScript I think