# Add file to Itunes com

Tags: c#, windows, com, itunes

I saw the post ([Adding song to itunes with C# sdk/api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585878/adding-song-to-itunes-with-c-sdk-api)) about this, but following the link couldn't find any solid help..
Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks,
Max

Comment: As a thought, is there a way to make sure that if the song I am trying to add through C# is already in the library, not to add it? (Check by meta data).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interacting with iTunes in C# isn't all that bad.

**Step 1**
Add a project reference to the iTunes.exe file in your Program Files directory. This will add a reference to `iTunesLib`.

**Step 2**
Create a new `iTunesLib.iTunesAppClass` instance.

**Step 3**
Use the `iTunesAppClass.LibraryPlaylist.AddFile()` method.

To ensure you aren't adding a duplicate file, you would have to check in the `LibraryPlaylist.Tracks` property to see if the file is already there. It's got a `get_ItemByName()` method you could try. If all else fails, you can just loop through the tracks to see if it's there.